# Infer geometric sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

[Haskell](https://haskell.org) has this neat(-looking) feature where you can give it three numbers and it can infer an arithmetic sequence from them. For example, `[1, 3..27]` is equivalent to `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]`.

That's cool and all but arithmetic sequences are fairly limiting. Addition, *pfft*. Multiplication's where it's at. Wouldn't it be cooler if it did geometric sequences like `[1, 3..27]` returning `[1, 3, 9, 27]`?

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes three positive integers **a**, **b**, and **c** and outputs `[a, b, b × (b ÷ a), b × (b ÷ a)2, ..., x]` where **x** is the greatest integer ≤ **c** that can be represented as `b × (b ÷ a)n` where **n** is a positive integer.

That is, the output should be **r**, such that:

```
r0 = a
r1 = b
rn = b × (b ÷ a)n-1
rlast = greatest integer ≤ c that can be represented as b × (b ÷ a)n
         where n is a positive integer
```

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- **b** will always be divisible by **a**.
- **a** < **b** ≤ **c**
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions (Mathematica might have one :P) that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

```
a   b   c     r

1   2   11    [1, 2, 4, 8]
2   6   100   [2, 6, 18, 54]
3   12  57    [3, 12, 48]
4   20  253   [4, 20, 100]
5   25  625   [5, 25, 125, 625]
6   42  42    [6, 42]
```

In a few better formats:

```
1 2 11
2 6 100
3 12 57
4 20 253
5 25 625
6 42 42

1, 2, 11
2, 6, 100
3, 12, 57
4, 20, 253
5, 25, 625
6, 42, 42
```

Comment: @Adám No. (see the first test case)

Comment: Note that the formula is simply **b^n/a^n-1**. Starting at **n=0**

Comment: Of course Mathematica has a built-in...

Comment: is it acceptable if the results are not exactly integers due to floating point errors?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
~↑≤Ṡ¡o//
```

Input is in order **b, c, a**.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr//9@4oaR4omk4bmgwqFvLy////82/zEwMP8y)

### Explanation

```
~↑≤Ṡ¡o//  Implicit inputs.
       /  a/b as exact rational number.
     o/   Divide by a/b (so multiply by b/a).
    ¡     Iterate that function
   Ṡ      on a. Result is the infinite list [a, b, b^2/a, b^3/a^2, ..
 ↑        Take elements from it while
~ ≤       they are at most c.
```

The control flow in this program is a bit hard to follow.
First, **b** is fed to the rightmost `/`, producing a function `/b` that divides by **b**.
Next, `~` splits the remaining program into three parts: `~(↑)(≤)(Ṡ¡o//b)`.
This feeds **c** to `≤` and **a** to `Ṡ¡o//b`, and combines the results with `↑`.
The result of `≤c` is a function that checks if its argument is at most **c**, and `↑≤c` takes the longest prefix of elements for which this holds.

It remains to show how `(Ṡ¡o//b)a` evaluates to the desired infinite list.
The part in parentheses is split into `Ṡ(¡)(o//b)`.
Then `Ṡ` feeds **a** to `o//b`, feeds the result to `¡`, and then gives **a** to its second argument.
The expression `(o//b)a` gives a function that takes a number and divides it by **a/b**, and `¡` iterates this function on its second argument, which is **a**.

Here is a series of transformations that visualize the explanation:

```
  (~↑≤Ṡ¡o//) b c a
= (~↑≤Ṡ¡o/(/b)) c a
= ~(↑)(≤)(Ṡ¡o/(/b)) c a
= ↑(≤c)((Ṡ¡o/(/b)) a)
= ↑(≤c)(Ṡ(¡)(o/(/b)) a)
= ↑(≤c)(¡(o/(/b)a) a)
= ↑(≤c)(¡(/(/ba))a)
Last line in English: takeWhile (atMost c) (iterate (divideBy (divideBy b a)) a)
```

Alternative solution using explicit variables in order **a, b, c**:

```
↑≤⁰¡*/⁵²
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
a,b,c=input()
x=b/a
while c/a:print a;a*=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnSSfZNjOvoLREQ5OrwjZJP5GrPCMzJ1UhWT/RqqAoM69EIdE6Ucu24v9/Ix0zHUMDAwA)

#### Recursive approach, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to ovs</sup>

```python
f=lambda a,b,c:c/a*[a]and[a]+f(b,b*b/a,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnSSfZKlk/USs6MTYxLwVIaqdpJOkkaSXpJ@oka/4vKMrMK1FI0zDSMdMxNDDQ/A8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 35 bytes

```
f=(a,b,c)=>c//a?[a]+f(b,b*b/a,c):[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/8/zVYjUSdJJ1nT1i5ZXz/RPjoxVjtNI0knSStJPxEobBUd@7@gKDOvRCNNw0jHTMfQwEBT8z8A)

Comment: people actually remember this language? :D

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I [actively](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151731/make-me-an-upside-down-christmas-tree/151739#151739) [use](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154917/59487) [it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154686/perfect-squares-without-borders/154701#154701) :)

Comment: I know that I am probably not going to receive any answer, but why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Takes input as `(b,c)(a)`.

```js
(b,c)=>g=a=>a>c?[]:[a,...g(b,b*=b/a)]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

(b,c)=>g=a=>a>c?[]:[a,...g(b,b*=b/a)]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(2,11)(1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(6,100)(2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(12,57)(3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(20,253)(4)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(42,42)(6)))
```

#### Commented

```js
(b, c) =>                 // main function taking b and c
  g = a =>                // g = recursive function taking a
    a > c ?               //   if a is greater than c:
      []                  //     stop recursion and return an empty array
    :                     //   else:
      [ a,                //     return an array consisting of a, followed by 
        ...g(             //     the expanded result of a recursive call to g()
          b,              //       with a = b
          b *= b / a      //       and b = b * ratio
        ) ]               //     end of recursive call
```

Comment: Rearranging the arguments gives me `(b,c)=>g=a=>a>c?[]:[a,...g(b,b*=b/a)]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
PowerRange[#,#3,#2/#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCoMwFEV/5eIDp1eamGqnSj5BuoYMocTqoAUJOIR8e/ocLpxzOVtIS9xCWj@hznihTr8zHu@wf6MjJsPU3cm3dTrWPblMVBgNbiMaxuyIvEcLay1y1oyOobUUWWAQVuoSIyRH/7zkIZWS9aaU@gc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 38 bytes

```
f(a,b,c)=powers(b/a,logint(c\a,b/a),a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMwDAS/InKyQCG2E7en9iOpD4ppQsA0Ii2Uvt6VDgsz2pXwufebtLY6poUK3uT4Ps@3Wwamemz76@PKQ6uBkRgbi9SfY@jvIKeVDJ1JB4VrdSsBIxLMcyCIBCFkFYWLsvcmo5Ie0tVk0pXXpNEsGek2JjN9maIlZ2x/)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
x=lambda a,b,c,i=0,q=[]:a*(b/a)**i>c and q or x(a,b,c,i+1,q+[a*(b/a)**i])
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoMwFIThvafIMtEpTZ4mQiG9iLhI4qJCq0Zc2NOntpSWwMDAx788t9s81afw@ZR2e3cPPzjm4BEwWolou/7iSu7PTpTleA3MTQOLbF7Zzr9ZpRCr7h/1Ii3rOG2c71yBoJQQoih@RjBQUuZYQxF0m2MDkiBd56oPgiGdq0FDx96YXg)

Thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod) and [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729) for helping me reduce quite some bytes!

Comment: `def + return -> lambda`. Python tips.

Comment: Also you can `import*`.

Comment: you can use `while i<=c:i++` (instead list comprehension+log) to save a lot of bytes

Comment: @Rod How should I use the while loop without the log? idk how long to iterate

Comment: You can use `while a*(b/a)**i<=c` (this is what I meant to write on the other comment, idk what happened)

Comment: All suggestions considered. Thanks for -19 bytes.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##VcpBC8IgHIbx@z6FR3Vv5F/bgsC@yNhB3SGh3Bw72Kc3iih2euDHszy325zMIXxaa7F39/CTYw4eAdEqZDuMFye5PzohZbwG5tLEMptXVvh3awm5Hf7TKOqyxrRxXjhBg0gI0TQ/0@hBSu3RgDS68x5P0Aq6M2@tLw).

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b,c)exp(log(a):log(b/a):log(c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRJ0knWTO1okAjJz9dI1HTCkQl6UMZyZqa//8DAA)

Turns out @LuisMendo's MATL approach also saves 3 bytes in Octave, despite repeating `log` three times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
{$^a,$^b,$b²/$a...^*>$^c}
{$^a,*×$^b/$a...^*>$^c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoMwEAXQq3xk6EIkZkaTLtQcJRJLs2ppsStRz@GBerBo4C3e9zm/bHovuEUMaSUfqvJ/kJ9qCkopXzryjz39woKCRgwOa8RG414gfmb0DAGzq9ALLFjr3AYsMPfcFqIhpsk3V2DF5Fu0cnFdOgE)

Perl 6's sequence operator `...` can infer geometric series natively.

Update:  ...It *can*, but in this situation not inferring it is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Input in the order `c,b,a`

```
ÝmI¹Ý<m/ʒ¹›_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v8wNWFiMWX//8OdbUnCucOdPG0vypLCueKAul///zE5MgoxMgoz)

**Explanation**

```
Ý              # push the range [0 ... c]
 m             # raise b to the power of each
  I            # push a
   ¹Ý          # push the range [0 ... c]
     <         # decrement each
      m        # push a to the power of each
       /       # elementwise division of ranges
        ʒ      # filter, keep only elements that are
         ¹›_   # not greater than c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
t:,qtiw^w]x/tb>~)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKp7AkszyuPLZCvyTJrk7z/39DCy4zLiMA)

Just to get the ball rolling in MATL. I can't imagine there isn't a less verbose way of solving this.

Comment: ... No triple negation please.

Comment: @user202729 I don't see how you could not have gotten that that wasn't an accident.:)

Comment: Don't you mean "I don't see how you could not have gotten that that wasn't done unintentionally" :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino No.

Comment: [Keep the ball rolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155060/36398)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 35 bytes

```
(a#b)c|a>c=[]|d<-div b a*b=a:(b#d)c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczNCgIhFIbhfVfxgS00CPSMGkR2I9HCnyBpZoqKVnPvdmbn9uHlvcfP4zaOrckokspLPOdwuS7ltC/1h4S4SyEeZRJF5TbFOiOgPDfA613nL7aQBgIgBWN6pVU9q9Y9D8yGY3fo1bKSViA39OxWdgqeXM@e2fLDUvsD)

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczBCsIwEATQu18xUA8NSEm2SXrql4iHbS1aTNugHvz7uLntZQYewzz581pSKqXlZjLzuHHG8svXdDzAl5pT19Wab2XjdceI@3EC8nvdvzijdWgAMnBOK1WNotZq7oWdjMOg1YuSNaDQaw6Vg0GkoDkKe/nwVP4). (more "in the spirit of the challenge", terrible floating point error)

Comment: @user202729: please post it as a separate answer (but save a byte: `exp<$>[...]`)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
y/ivZlZ}3$:W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v1I/sywqJ6rWWMUq/P9/Iy4zLkMDAwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L9SP7MsKieq1ljFKvy/S8h/Qy4jLkMQYcZlaGDAZcxlaMRlas5lwmVkwGVkasxlCiS5zECYy8QIhAA).

#### Explanation

```
y     % Implicitly take two inputs, and duplicate the first onto the top
/     % Divide
i     % Take third input
v     % Vertically concatenate the three numbers into a column vector
Zl    % Binary logarithm, element-wise
Z}    % Split the vector into its three components
3$:   % Three-input range. Arguments are start, step, upper limit
W     % 2 raised to that, element-wise. Implicit display
```

Comment: This is really nice. I was struggling with reusing `a` and `c` (I have many failed attempts starting with `y/i`), but using this method, you neatly keep everything together.

Comment: this approach was actually 3 bytes shorter in Octave too.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 38 bytes

Include `+3` for `-n` (the `use 5.10.0` to unlock the perl 5.10 features is free)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use 5.10.0;
/ \d+/;say,$_*=$&/$`until($_+=0)>$'
```

Then run as:

```
geosequence.pl <<< "1 3 26"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 50 bytes

```
g: func[a b c][if a <= c[print a g b b * b / a c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYsxDsIwDEX3nuLNSIjEbYKE4BKsUYY2baMuFarohDh7cMUYyx7@e/7bNJbnNBJiyTfmfU2hZyDFsMz03B@k8NqW9a0hqxg46V00pagVLIK1zf/lcz7m22SFHmtMxVus4K4V7xCDuLYSTileXCU8nRxbfg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
ÆWpX zVpXÉÃf§U
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xldwWCB6VnBYycNmp1U=&input=NjI1LDUsMjU=)

---

### Explanation

```
                    :Implicit input of integers U=c, V=a & W=b
Æ         Ã         :Range [0,U) and pass each X through a function
 WpX                :  W to the power of X
     z              :  Floor divide by
      VpXÉ          :  V to the power of X-1
           f§U      :Filter elements less than or equal to U
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 63 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a b c=takeWhile((>=)c)[a:map(\n=b*b^n/a^n)[0..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcu9CsIwEADg3ae4oUMiWP8GQYiTDoJbB4fawuUaNZi7FhsFX97Tb/8oBRTlvnulAIxRNPLQPzNUuTvIe1IgeCCX8RHO95iCMTtnyda4ZRzMRZyf@lbm2IqtF2XZNFpl/HcHBSxhDauNfuma8Dbq7HjS/UeQI40/)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 31 bytes

Takes input from user and outputs in `Ans`.  I solved for n in c = b<sup>n</sup> / a<sup>n-1</sup>, getting n = 1 + ln(c/b) / ln(b/a).  That's the same as n = 1 + log<sub>b/a</sub>(c/b).  For the purposes of golfing, I start my sequence at -1 and end it at n-1 rather than 0 to n.

```
Prompt A,B,C
seq(B(B/A)^N,N,-1,logBASE(C/B,B/A
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 38 bytes

```apl
{(g≤⊃⌽⍵)⊆g←f,(⍵[1]*p+1)÷(f←⊃⍵)*p←⍳⊃⌽⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbmXECOpz@QY/A/DUhWa6Q/6lzyqKv5Uc/eR71bNR91taUDhdN0NIC8aMNYrQJtQ83D2zVAakGqgEq0CkDs3s1wTbX//6cpGCoYKRgacqUBKTMFQwMDIMtYwdBIwdQcyDJRMDJQMDI1BjJNgbSCmZEpkGmmYGIERAA)

Prefix Dfn. Takes input in order `a b c`, and uses `⎕IO←0` (**I**ndex **O**rigin)

Thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer for shaving 6 bytes out of this before I even posted it.

#### How?

```apl
{(g≤⊃⌽⍵)⊆g←f,(⍵[1]*p+1)÷(f←⊃⍵)*p←⍳⊃⌽⍵} ⍝ Prefix Dfn. Input ⍵ is a vector
                                    ⌽⍵  ⍝ Reverse ⍵. Yields c b a
                                   ⊃    ⍝ Pick the first element (c)
                                  ⍳     ⍝ Index. Yields the integers 0..c-1
                                p←      ⍝ Assign to the variable p
                               *        ⍝ Exponentiate
                         (f←⊃⍵)         ⍝ Pick the first element of ⍵ (a) and assign to f
                                        ⍝ This yields the vector (a^0, a^1, ..., a^c-1)
                        ÷               ⍝ Element-wise division
                    p+1)                ⍝ The vector 1..c
                   *                    ⍝ Exponentiate
              (⍵[1]                     ⍝ Second element (because of ⎕IO←0) of ⍵ (b)
                                        ⍝ This yields the vector (b^1, b^2, ..., b^c)
            f,                          ⍝ Prepend f (a). This yields the vector 
                                        ⍝ (a, b^1/a^0, b^2/a^1, ...)
          g←                            ⍝ Assign the vector to g
         ⊆                              ⍝ Partition. This takes a boolean vector as left
                                        ⍝ argument and drops falsy elements of the right argument.
     ⊃⌽⍵)                               ⍝ Pick the last element of ⍵ (c)
  (g≤                                   ⍝ Check if each element of g≤c. Yields the boolean
                                        ⍝ vector that is the left argument for ⊆
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

This takes arguments **a b** on the left and **c** on the right,

```apl
{⊃(⍵∘≥⊆⊢)⊣/⍵2⍴⍺,÷\⍵⍴⌽⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR13NGo96tz7qmPGoc@mjrrZHXYs0H3Ut1geKGT3q3fKod5fO4e0xIBVATs9eIL/2/39DBSOFNAVDQy4jBTMQw8CAy1jBECRmas5lomBkAGQZmRpzmQJJINPMyJTLTMEEJG9iBAA)

There is likely a shorter way, but I thought that `÷\` was cute.

#### Explained:

`{...}` Anonomous function ⍺ is `a b`, `⍵` is `c`. Lets say `a b c = 2 6 100`

`⌽⍺` Reverse `⍺`: `6 2`

`⍵⍴` Repeat `⍵` times: `6 2 6 2 6 2 6 2 ...`

`÷\` Reduce by division on prefixes: `6 (6÷2) (6÷(2÷6)) (6÷(2÷(6÷2))).. = 6 3 18 9 54 ..`

`⍺,` Prepend `⍺`: `2 6 6 3 18 9 54 27 162 81 ...`

`⊣/⍵2⍴` Get every other element (plus some trailing repeats):

`⍵2⍴` Make an `⍵` row, `2` column matrix from `2 6 6 3 18 9 54 ...`

`⊣/` Get the first column

`⊆⊢` Split the array into blocks where

`⍵∘≥` `⍵` is greater than or equal to all the elements

`⊃` Take the first such block

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
ü╞¥ß¥║/,5å╘⌂åº
```

16 bytes when unpacked,

```
E~Y/y{;^<}{[*gfm
```

[Run and debug online!](http://staxlang.xyz/index.html#c=E%7EY%2Fy%7B%3B%5E%3C%7D%7B%5B*gfm&i=%5B2%2C+1%2C+11%5D%0A%0A%5B6%2C+2%2C+100%5D%0A%0A%5B12%2C+3%2C+57%5D%0A%0A%5B20%2C+4%2C+253%5D%0A%0A%5B25%2C+5%2C+625%5D%0A%0A%5B42%2C+6%2C+42%5D&a=1&m=1)

Takes input in the form of `[b, a, c]`.

Pretty sure @recursive has better solutions.

### Explanation

```
E~                              Parse  input, put `c` on input stack
  Y/                            Store `a` in register `y` and calculate `b`/`a`
    y                           Put `y` back to main stack, stack now (from top to bottom): [`a`, `b`/`a`]
     {   }{  gf                 generator
      ;^<                       Condition: if the generated number is smaller than the top of input stack (i.e. `c`)
           [*                   duplicate the second item in main stack and multiply it with the item at the top
                                   i.e. multiply last generated value by `b/a` and generate the value
              m                 Output array, one element on each line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 73 bytes

```
readIO
k=i
readIO
j=i
readIO
r=j/k
a=k
lbla
printInt a
a*r
b=i-a+1
if b a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058r2zaTC8rMQjCLbLP0s7kSbbO5cpJyErkKijLzSjzzShQSuRK1iriSbDN1E7UNuTLTFJIUEv///2/03@S/mTEA)

We read the three numbers. Calculate the common ratio by the second number/ first one. Then we run through the series until we are greater than the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 82 bytes

```
n;f(a,b,c){float r=0;for(n=0;r<=c;)(r=pow(b,n)/pow(a,n++-1))<=c&&printf("%f ",r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/RCsIgFIbve4rDoFByNJ2uwPYmuzHBCNZZWNBF9OrZMepiKYh6/u/To6@P3qeENjAnDsLzRxgnd4PYNzZMkSGtcd97y1nsL9OdHQTyTd44get1LTmndLW6xBPeAquWASoRuX0mOsPZnZDxxWMBNAKTApQAKbn9FH7OgBIUaNgNOGD1DQMjtCO6aQpcQQdyB0bPhZZoksy2EFoKQP/dr6mbhqZpC15Tkl@eCybD1JQyhWAooTdMDucSfUGrPAuno@KPfaaXD6M7XlM9nt8)

Calculates and prints `r_n = b^n/a^(n-1)` until `r_n > c`.

Must be compiled with `-lm`!

Comment: 69 bytes `n;f(a,b,c){for(float r=n=0;r=pow(b/a,n++)*a,r<=c&&printf("%f ",r););}`